# private ip address setup on CoreOS

Tags: ip, coreos

I am working on setting up private ip for my CoreOS on Vultr.  Vultr creates a private ip but it's not setup.  When I ping from one vps to the destination with it's private ip it does not work.

If I have private ip 10.99.0.10 created how do I set it up to use it in CoreOS?  The closest documentation I am looking at is this [floating ip assignment](https://www.upcloud.com/support/configure-floating-ip-coreos/) and this [coreos documentation](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/network-config-with-networkd.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a file on path /etc/systemd/network/static.network with the following content:

[Match]
Name=eth1

[Link]
MTUBytes=1450

[Network]
Address=10.99.0.10/16
After that you can chmod the file:

> sudo chmod 0644 /etc/systemd/network/static.network

And then execute the following:

> sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
>   if you ping from another server you should be able to see packets flowing.